# Seeking online sources where companies offer free labels for their products (beer, wine or other spirits)?

Tags: breweries, distilleries

Seeking online sources where companies offer free labels for their products (beer, wine or other spirits)?

A few years ago I discovered that [Crown Royal](http://crownroyalshop.com/index.php/categories-products/custom-labels/) offers free custom made labels (restriction do apply). The labels fit right over the original labels in such a way that no one could tell the the original one were still on the bottle. I had much fun buying some Crown Royal with custom labels put in them at Christmas time. The looks we got when they read the labels were truly amazing.

My question is quite simple: **Are there any other breweries or alcohol producing companies that offer free labels online for their alcoholic beverages?**

Answer (score 1):

**Free, just the label, can be placed over existing label**

- Josh cellars, will give out free labels for their wine that will be shipped to you that can be placed over existing labels that you have already purchased. [Josh Cellars custom label page](http://www.joshcellars.com/custom-labels.html)
- Woodford Reserve will print custom labels and mail to you. [Woodford Reserve custom labels](http://www.woodfordreserve.com/distillery/labels/)

**Purchase special labeled beverages to be shipped, includes alcoholic beverage**

- Gordon & MacPhail will allow you to purchase custom labeled products from their site but it doesn't look like you can place a label over an existing product. [Gordon & MacPhail custom labeled products](http://www.gordonandmacphail.com/personalised-labels.html)
- Windsor vineyards will customize a label for free and then send the wine to you. [Windsor vienyards label site](http://www.windsorvineyards.com/personalized-wine-labels)

**Not Free but still custom**

- In Milwaukee Sprecher brewing will do this for their beer or soda. Not sure if they will ship it. I've not heard of others but I'm from Milwaukee and don't know much about what breweries outside this area will do. [Sprecher's Private Labeled Beer & Soda](https://www.sprecherbrewery.com/private_label.php)

Comment: @Ken Graham I've updated to include some free that they will mail to you, some that you can purchase.